# Extend numpy array in a way compatible with builtin arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write code that would not depend on whether the user uses `np.array` or a builtin array. I am trying to avoid checking object types, etc. The only problem that I have is in extending arrays. For example, if I have two Python arrays, `a` and `b`, to extend the first by the second, I can either do `a = a + b`, or `a.extend(b)`. On the other hand, if `a` is a numpy array, I need to use `np.append` or something else.

Is there a quick way to extend arrays independently of whether they are `np` arrays or Python arrays?

Comment: What is a builtin array?  Do you mean list?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Yes, sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy's append() works on lists too!

```
>>> np.append([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
```

If you want to automatically make the result be the same type as the input, try this:

```
mytype = type(a)
arr = np.append(a, b)
result = mytype(arr)
```

Comment: I don't care about a specific type... as long as it's an iterable. But as input I expect either a Python list or an nparray, so this works very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even if your function is flexible on input, your output should be of specific type. So I would just convert to desired output type.

For example, if my functions is working with `numpy.array` and returns a `numpy.array`, but I want to allow `list`s to be input as well, the first thing I would do is convert `list`s to `numpy.array`s.

Like this:

```
def my_func(a, b):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    b = np.asarray(b)
    # do my stuff here
```

Comment: @Zhenya, yeah that's better, it is more general, e.g, it handles all iterables, not just lists, and it is shorter. Thank You.