# How to extend numpy arrray

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 numpy arrays and i want to combine these two array together using extend. 
eg:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]
```

what i want is
`c = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]`

It seems that I cannot use `extend` as python list. otherwise it will raise `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'extend'` error.

Currently I tried by transforming them into lists :

```
a_list = a.tolist()
b_list = b.tolist()
a_list.extend(b_list)
c = numpy.array(a_list)
```

I wonder if any better solution exist?

Comment: `np.concatenate`, `np.vstack` at least

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend numpy array in a way compatible with builtin arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940374/extend-numpy-array-in-a-way-compatible-with-builtin-arrays)

Comment: A technical point - the answers create a new array that incorporates the values from all input arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use -

```
np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
```

Or -

```
np.vstack((a,b))
```

Or -

```
a.append(b) # appends in-place, a will get modified directly
```

**Output**

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```